Web scraping Images with beautiful soup Issue
I am trying to web scrape images of female buzzcuts and store it in a folder so that I could later use it to train a model. Yet, I am running into a problem where the code outputs "DONE", but my images folder is empty. I tried debugging and got the error (I removed the debugging part of the code):
Invalid URL '/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png': 
No scheme supplied  

import hashlib, io, requests, pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image
import os

def get_content_from_url(url):
    options = ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run Chrome in headless mode
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    driver.get(url)
    page_content = driver.page_source
    driver.quit()
    return page_content

def parse_image_urls(content, classes, location, source):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
    results = []
    for a in soup.findAll(attrs={"class": classes}):
        name = a.find(location)
        if name and name.get(source) not in results:
            results.append(name.get(source))
    return results

def save_urls_to_csv(image_urls):
    df = pd.DataFrame({"links": image_urls})
    df.to_csv("links.csv", index=False, encoding="utf-8")

def get_and_save_image_to_file(image_url, output_dir):
    image_content = requests.get(image_url).content
    image_file = io.BytesIO(image_content)
    image = Image.open(image_file).convert("RGB")
    filename = hashlib.sha1(image_content).hexdigest()[:10] + ".png"
    file_path = output_dir / filename
    image.save(file_path, "PNG", quality=80)

def main():
    url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=female+buzzcut&udm=2"  # Replace with the actual URL
    content = get_content_from_url(url)
    image_urls = parse_image_urls(
        content=content, classes="srp EIlDfe", location="img", source="src"
    )
    save_urls_to_csv(image_urls)

    for image_url in image_urls:
        get_and_save_image_to_file(
            image_url, output_dir=Path("./images")
        )
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    print("Done!")



Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.


Invalid URL '/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png': No scheme supplied

You need an entire URL. What you pulled out of the page element was a relative link (in this case, root relative).
You're extracting the src which may not always contain a full URL including the scheme (e.g. http:// or https://) or the host portion (google.com) of the URL, such as in this case when a relative URL was found. Normally, your browser resolves relative links against the current URL, so that's not a problem when viewing a page in your browser. But in the context of your Python script, you need to make sure you fill in this information when it is not present in the src of the element.
You can do do this correctly making use of urljoin to join the current web location with the relative link:
For example:
from urllib.parse import urljoin
src = '/images/foo.png' # e.g. <img src="/images/foo.png">
url = 'https://example.com/some/page.html'

link_location = urljoin(url, src)
print(link_location)  # the actual location

Applying this to your code, you can add an extra current_url parameter to handle this in your parse_image_urls
from urllib.parse import urljoin

def parse_image_urls(current_url, content, classes, location, source):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
    results = []
    for a in soup.findAll(attrs={"class": classes}):
        name = a.find(location)
        src = name.get(source)
        if src:
            location = urljoin(current_url, src)
            if location not in results:
                results.append(location)
    return results
# ...
# and the calling code...
def main():
    url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=female+buzzcut&udm=2"  # Replace with the actual URL
    content = get_content_from_url(url)
    image_urls = parse_image_urls(
        current_url=url,
        content=content, classes="srp EIlDfe", location="img", source="src"
    )
    # ...

Keep in mind, you're potentially going to run into other contents in an image's src attribute that are going to have a similar kind of problem. For example, an image source may not be a remote link at all, but rather is a base64 data blob. So, you will probably need your function to handle such cases as well.
